# How do you update the document inside document? MongoDB Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I wish to update an "info" inside a document, the only problem is that I store it as a doc and cannot seem to access it.

```
Document doc = new Document("name", "Test")
    .append("type", "database")
    .append("count", 1)
    .append("info", new Document("a", 23).append("b", 12));
```

Now I wish to append new information into "info", `("c", 8)`
I have tried `doc.append("info", ... )` but it only override the data.
I was thinking of creating new Document and setting it equal to the document inside doc such as

```
Document temp = new Document();
    temp.append("info", doc.get("info"));
```

and updating it but it does not work. I appreciate any suggestion or new methods. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the $set operation on an update of a Mongo document. This can update individual fields without disturbing other fields.

Something like:

```
Document selectQuery = new Document("name", "test");
Document updateInstruction = new Document("$set", new Document("info.c", "8"));
repo.updateOne(selectQuery, updateInstruction);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, replacing the entire subdocument info with a new version or appending a field to the subdocument info?

Comment: Thanks for the help! it works. I been scratching my head for past 3 hours and created stack overflow account to ask a question. I can finally sleep.